# query data from more than one table

Tags: php, search, multiple-tables

I have a search function that currently grabs data from one table, and I'd like to grab data from an additional table, as well.

```
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_customer');
$this->db->select('in_customer_id, st_company_name, in_customer_type, st_customer_account, st_customer_state_id, flg_customer_account_type, in_status, dt_added_date, st_tag');
if(trim($action['searchtxt'])!='')
    $this->db->like('st_company_name', html_entity_decode($action['searchtxt']));
```

The view:

```
   <div class="floatl"  style="width:250px;">
      <form name="frm" action="<?php echo $index_url; ?>customers/search/" method="post">
        <div class="floatl">                
          <input name="Search" type="text" class="textboxsearch" id="Search" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="<?php if($searchtxt!=''){ echo $searchtxt; } else{ echo 'Search'; }?>" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
            <div class="floatl searchicon">
          <input type="image"  src="<?=$admin_base_url?>images/textbox_search.gif" alt="" width="22" height="22" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <font class="txt9">(i.e. Company, Account name)</font>
      </form>          
    </div>
```

The table I want to additionally search is called `tbl_admin_user`.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to brush up on your SQL a little, especially take a look at [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

With that said, after re-reading your question it appears that you are attempting to search particular columns for fairly specific data within multiple tables.  First you might want to look into using [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) instead of [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).

Second, depending on how you're displaying the results you you'll probably either write two separate queries and then loop through each of the separate results and display them.  A Union or Join might be possible but also might be difficult to display the results accurately if the table structures are really different.

Comment: Correct - I'm trying to grab specific data from multiple tables and display an array based on an id.  I actually just found this, which is almost exactly the same problem I'm having: http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3610400.htm.  Curious if this solution is a good one...

Comment: The answer posted on that forum combined with gaining a little more knowledge of the items I mentioned in my post should get you well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an ORM/framework to access data, which one are you using.

Anyway, you are probably looking for [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or [union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).